# How to Calculate Percentages for Groups in SQL

Tags: sql, select, sum, window-functions

I have a table that looks something like this

```
Class     ID        Value
  A        1         300
  A        2         200
  A        3         500
  B        1         300
  B        2         300
  C        1        1000
```

Is there a way of using SQL to calculate the percentage share each ID has to the class.

For example, the percentages for class A would be 30% to id 1, 20% to ID 2, and 50% to id 3 and so on for the other classes:

```
Class     ID        Value    Percentage
  A        1         300         30%
  A        2         200         20%
  A        3         500         50%
  B        1         300         50%
  B        2         300         50%
  C        1        1000         100%
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: oracle, sql-server, postgresql...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions (if your database, which you did not disclose, supports them):

```
select
    t.*,
    1.0 * value / sum(value) over(partition by class) ratio
from mytable t
```

This gives you a ratio, that is a value between `0` and `1` - I find that this is more relevant than a percentage, but you can multiply that by `100` if you like.